# How to set up Vue 3 Composition API (Typescript) to push user-inputted value to array

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to build a basic todo list app using Vue 3 Composition API with Typescript. I configured the submit function in the form to call `addTodo()` in the setup function. My intention is to push user-inputted values to the `listItems` array, which is initialized with the `ref` method. In my `addTodo()` function I added `listItems.value.push(newTodo.value)` in order to pass the inputted value to the array. However, I am getting an error on the newTodo.value parameter, saying `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`. I am new to Composition API in Vue 3. How can I go about resolving this type error?

See my code below:

Template

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <form @submit.prevent="addTodo()">
          <label>New ToDo</label>
          <input
              v-model="newTodo"
              name="newTodo"
              autocomplete="off"
          >
          <button>Add ToDo</button>
      </form>

    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="listItem in listItems" :key="listItem">
          <h3>{{ listItem }}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Form',
  
  setup() {
    const newTodo = ref('');
    const listItems = ref([]);

    const addTodo = () => {
      listItems.value.push(newTodo.value)
      newTodo.value = ''
    }
    
    return { newTodo, listItems, addTodo }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare typing for `listItems` like this:

```
const listItems = ref<string[]>([]);
```

otherwise TypeScript won't know what type of array `listItems` is

Comment: thanks! This works. Going back through my notes for Comp API, it's my understanding that reactive method is applicable to objects and arrays, while ref is applicable to primitives. Therefore, should I use reactive instead of ref in this case since I'm dealing with an array?

Comment: Can't speak from my experience because I haven't used Vue in a long time and haven't spent too much time with composition API, but I think [this](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/801#issuecomment-757587022) will help you decide on which to use. tl;dr is: use `ref` if you need to reassign the array (e.g. fetching new data from API), and use `reactive` if you don't need to reassign it, so in this case `reactive` probably suits you more

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 ref is applicable to everything. That reactive supports objects means there are less reasons to use ref for that but there still may be cases. The obvious one is when you need to have unambiguous uninitialized value (null) without relying on object contents (e.g. checking `length`). In your case reactive is ok

Comment: I see, thanks. When is it absolutely necessary to use ```reactive``` instead of ```ref```? From what I'm seeing, ```reactive``` cannot be used to handle primitives directly, without taking away the reactive properties of those primitives, so what is an example of a case where ```reactive``` should be used instead of ```ref```?